# Why is my HDR in blender only working on the objects and not appearing in the world itself?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri, world

[image]

There is some sort of grid pattern in which the HDRI does not appear. I opened another project and the HDRI seemed to work, but it doesn't work in this project though.

Answer (score 1):

The grid pattern indicates transparency because the film is set to transparent, so the background is transparent too.

[image]